# I'm getting "no such table: main.auth_user__old" error. How to fix this?

Tags: django, authentication

I have tried what's out there to fix the error provided by people here.

- install Django 2.7.1
- delete db.sql3
- makemigrations, migrate, run server.

But none of this worked. Any other advice?

Comment: when did you get this error? can you add more details to your question?

Comment: I fixed the error by upgrading Django. Apparently I should have gone for pip3 install Django==2.7.1. It worked for me! Thanks Andrey!